# Project management with web email clients

Tags: php, mysql, tracking, email

I am thinking of writing a spec project management webpage. I wonder of anybody have some idea how to start.

Requirements:

1, Needs a SQL email DB to be able to alter for user

2, these email addresses will be grouped for different mass-emails

3, rich email sending with attached files

4, tracking of emails

in other words

A orchestral concert needs players; I have a list of players and every concert has a different concert program so I need different groups to mail out the application forms. As they would reply on the email I need to able to see those replies.
add:I need to be able to see who has replied and if they available for that concert; I also need to be able to track which player can come and who can't so the concert won't fail because of lack of the players:)

Is there any open source apps that already has been written or where to start?

Thanks a lot

Andras

Comment: So you are really looking for an advanced mass E-Mailing application? Not sure where project management comes into play.

Comment: Thanks Pekka for your question. I need to be able to see who has replied and if they available for that concert; and if I need to find someone else I have to send the same application form again to new players.

Comment: I see (you should really edit that info into your question though). That reeks like a custom job to me - it's a very specific requirement. But maybe you're lucky. Maybe one of the few PHP-based booking platforms (for hotels and such) might be an option? I don't have experience with any of them though, so I can't make a recommendation

Answer (score 1):

That's not an exact answer, but it does not fit into a comment, so...

Looks like you don't need project management software. Mass mailing services and programs are more than capable of meeting your requirements. I've performed an assesment of MM (mass mailing) programs and services abiut two mongth ago, so you might want to evaluate:

Programs:

1. http://www.massmailingnews.com/ - free of charge, intellectual csv import (column selection, additional information etc.), email composer, send via SMTP, 3rd party (like IIS SMTP) or direct (needs DNS), saves mails and "campaigns" (sets of addressess and messages), fancy GUI.
2. http://www.group-mail.com/asp/common/default.asp - configurable recipient data, import from address book, file or database, message saving, message templates, group management, etc. Free (limited number of recipients), licenses start from $139. Compare version at http://www.group-mail.com/asp/common/purchase.asp
3. http://www.amailsender.com/massmailer/ - trial, import from csv/database, primitive email composer, send via SMTP, $59.95 per license.
4. http://www.mailutilities.com/adr/ - looks like full-power smtp proxy, which could be used for mass mailing (though didn't yet understand how). Free of charge.

Paid services:

1. http://www.yourmailinglistprovider.com/  free 30-day trial, importing contacts, WYSIWYG message composer, reusing messages, message templates, sending delay. $3.75/month
2. http://www.amailsender.com/listmanageronline/ - very confusing interface, $9.85/month, uncertain set of features

I would recommend evaluating GroupMail, MassMailingNews and www.yourmailinglistprovider.com. If they are not suitable - develop some custom solution.

Comment: +1 for the good list, although the OP added some very specific requirements in the comments that make mass mailing software unusable

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I have scanned through these websites and I need a webapps so I can manage these concert from the 'cloud' :) and I also need to be able to track which player can come and who can't so the concert won't fail because of lack of the players:) thanks